# Changing global c variable inside a struct array

Tags: arrays, c, struct, global-variables

I have a case where I have defined a global struct array in a seperate header file that I want to be able to change from function in another file but I can not make it work, I believe that the problem can be simplified to the follwing:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct point{
    /*
    Measured points and reflector coordinates, both true and estimated
    are stored as points.
    */
    float x;    // x-coordinate [mm]
    float y;    // y-coordinate [mm]
} coordinates[3];


void set_value(){
    coordinates[0].x = 10.0;
    coordinates[1].x = 11.0;
    coordinates[2].x = 12.0;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    set_value();
    printf("[0]: %d, [1]: %d, [2]: %d", coordinates[0].x, coordinates[1].x, coordinates[2].x);

}
```

Which gives the following non-sensical output:

```
[0]: 0, [1]: 1076101120, [2]: 0
```

The output that I want is the follwoing:

```
[0]: 10.0, [1]: 11.0, [2]: 12.0
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

Edit:
It was just me forgetting to change `%d` to `%f` while testing out different struct types.

Comment: use `%f` instead of `%d` inside `printf`

Comment: Maybe ask your compiler to warn you about such mistakes by turning on all warnings and minding them helps in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
printf("[0]: %d, [1]: %d, [2]: %d", coordinates[0].x, coordinates[1].x, coordinates[2].x);
```

You used wrong control format for `printf`, it should be `%f` instead for floating variables:

```
printf("[0]: %f, [1]: %f, [2]: %f", coordinates[0].x, coordinates[1].x, coordinates[2].x);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get required output replace your `printf` in `main()`

from

```
printf("[0]: %d, [1]: %d, [2]: %d", coordinates[0].x, coordinates[1].x, coordinates[2].x);
```

To

```
printf("[0]: %.1f, [1]: %.1f, [2]: %.1f", coordinates[0].x, coordinates[1].x, coordinates[2].x);
```